# How to get response time to turnaround weekends and after business hours?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been working on this project for a while and i'm just getting nowhere so I figured i'd ask you guys here. There are a bunch of tasks: Quoting, Binding, Issuance...and they each have their own response times.

Quoting has to be done within 3 hours, while binding is 8 hours and issuance has a 2 day turnaround time. But, the issue is that the response times are based on only a 9:00 - 8:00 pm (est) time, excluding weekends and holidays. I have a holiday lookup table, as well as the task times indexed from another lookup table.

The part that I'm stuck is in regards to "stopping the clock" and having the task response time turn around to next day if it's after 8:00 pm.

This is the formula that I created to do so, but it's not working as it should because it will show the same time if I changed Time to (48,0,0) for issuance or Time(8,0,0) for binding. Column P3 has the start time.

```
=IF(AND(TEXT(P3,"dddd")="Friday",HOUR(P3)+MINUTE(P3)/60+SECOND(P3)/(60*60)>17),P3+TIME(15,0,0)+DAY(2),IF(HOUR(P3)+MINUTE(P3)/60+SECOND(P3)/(60*60)>17,P3+TIME(15,0,0),P3+Time(3,0,0)))
```

Thank you! Any help will be greatly appreciated guys!

Comment: Sounds like a very elaborate thing to do in Excel! Are you able to use a VBA custom function? It would require the workbook to be a macro-enabled workbook.

Comment: Yes @JoshJay, but I'm a novice when it comes to VBA, but I try to learn functions and also keep looking online for ideas

Answer (score 2):

Here's some untested and not fully implemented code for you to start with:

```
Function GetTurnaroundDateAndTime(TaskType As String, StartTime As Date, TaskTimeRange As Range, HolidayLookupRange As Range)
    Dim taskTime As Double
    Dim dayBegin As Double 'could be a parameter
    Dim dayEnd As Double 'could be a parameter
    Dim result As Date
    Dim isValid As Boolean
    Dim offset As Double

    dayBegin = 9 'could be a parameter
    dayEnd = 20 'could be a parameter
    offest = 0

    'Get Task Time in hours
    taskTime = GetTaskTime(TaskType, TaskTimeRange)

    'Calculate initial turnaround time (without regard to nights/weekends/holidays)
    result = DateAdd("h", taskTime + offset, StartTime)

    'check if it's a valid turnaround date and time, return if so
    isValid = False
    Do While isValid = False
        'check #1 - is the turnaround time before the day begins?
        If Hour(result) < 9 Then
            If Hour(StartTime) < 20 Then
                offset = offset - 20 + Hour(StartTime) 'check to see if a portion of the task time would be before end of day, subtract this amount from the offset
            End If
            offset = offset + 9 = Hour(result) 'gets the offset to the beginning of day
        ElseIf Weekday(result, vbSaturday) = 1 Then
            offset = offset + 48 'if we're on a Saturday, add two days
        ElseIf Weekday(result, vbSunday) = 1 Then
            offset = offset + 24 'if we're on a Sunday, add one day
        ElseIf IsHoliday(result, HolidayLookupRange) Then
            offset = offset + 24 'if we're on a holiday, add one day
        Else
            isValid = True
        End If

        result = DateAdd("h", taskTime + offset, StartTime) 're-evaluate result
    Loop

    GetTurnaroundDateAndTime = result
End Function

Function GetTaskTime(TaskType As String, TaskTimeRange As Range) As Double
    'TODO: implement function to lookup the task time from the table
    GetTaskTime = 3
End Function

Function IsHoliday(DateToLookup As Date, HolidayLookupRange As Range) As Boolean
    'TODO: implement function to lookup if date is a holiday
    IsHoliday = False
End Function
```

Here are some links that should help you get started with VBA:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f
- https://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut01.htm

You'll want to test a lot of different scenarios before feeling comfortable with the code. I just put something quick together!

Comment: wow, that looks complicated. I will definitely try to learn this, will update you!